# Window.onbeforeunload - know what the user clicked Angular 5

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular

I am currently developing an app using angular 5 .

Before the user leaves the page I check if they changed any form field and didnt submit. I have something like this

```
// lunch when closing the page o reload it
@HostListener('window:beforeunload', ['event'])
  beforeUnloadHander(event) {
    if(!this.accepted && this.details.length != 0){
    var message = 'Sure you want to leave?';
    if (typeof event == 'undefined') {
      event = window.event;
    }
    if (event) {
      event.returnValue = message;
      console.log(event)
    }
    // console.log(event.returnValue)
    return message;
    }
```

I get something like this on my panel

[image]

Question is now, I want to know what the user pressed. If he pressed [ Leave ] then run function a, if he presses [ Stay ] then run function b. It doesn't seem to be possible to achieve this...

Comment: If you also handle the "unload" event, you'll know that  the user chose "leave" if that event handler is invoked.

Comment: why donot you make use of alert or even a confirm dailouge which will have yes and no and you can capture that

Comment: When i use confirm chrome blocked it from showing and  I get a msg on my console "Blocked confirm ...."

Comment: @Pointy can you give more details ?

Comment: What higher level problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: @charlietfl I didn't understand exactly what you mean by higher level problem

Comment: Meaning why do you need to know if user leaves or not. There is no *"stay"* event you can listen to

Comment: I want to know what the user pressed. If he pressed [ Leave ] then run function a, if he presses [ Stay ] then run function b.

Comment: But there is no stay event. What are these functions needing to do? (ie higher level problem). Also not a good idea to do much in unload event. For example an api request is bad idea

Comment: The dialog has 2 option like on the picture Leave and Stay

Comment: Yes it certainly does but there is no event associated with staying and you have no access to that dialog

Comment: yes this is my question can i associate an event to stay or leave to run my functions

Comment: Have said several times ...NO. There is unload event but trying to do anything important there is not a good idea and you have left things too late

Comment: Why not you ngOnDestroy and run whatever function you need when the app is destroyed i.e. closes?

Comment: because the app does not make a call to  ngOnDestroy when you close it from the browser

Answer (score 0):

If the user clicked `reaload/leave` the browser will emmit the `unload` event, so you can do something like this:

```
  @HostListener('window:unload', ['$event'])
  unloadHandler(event) {
    // do something here
    console.log('unload event');
  }
```

If the user clicked cancel, nothing happens, the user is still on the page.

Hope it helps whoever read this.

Comment: This seems only to work if the user closes the page, not on refresh or navigation to another site. For which the beforeunload is called.

Answer (score -2):

Make your own message box and use promise to determine what user has pressed.

Comment: It's not possible to use a custom dialog with the "beforeunload" event.

Comment: @Pointy He's suggesting you just make a prompt with both options, then manually close the window if the user selects leave.

Comment: @DavidAnthonyAcosta right, but that's not at all the same as a "beforeunload" handler. The "beforeunload" event happens for anything that closes the window  (well within the abilities of the browser at least).